# Invalid CSS after "Κ": expected "{", was "" in codesandbox

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuetify.js, codesandbox

I created a vue [application with vuetify in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-tcyid)

The problem is codesandbox doesn't load sass file. I have sass-loader in package.json.

Not sure what the problem is and the message is not clear.

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "Κ": expected "{", was ""
        on line 1 of node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass
        from line 1 of /stdin
>> Κ
   ^
```

[image]

Comment: Is `node-sass` added as a dependency?

Comment: I don't think it must because `sass` is replace for `node-sass`